# Java ArrayList with customized AddAll method

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a custom class called `News` every news have a unique `id` for itself:

```
public class News{ 
    public long id;
    public String title;
    //...
}
```

now I want to use an customized `ArrayList` for my `dataset`

And this is my custom `ArrayList`:

```
public class NewsArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<News> {
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends News> c) {
        ArrayList<News> b = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean notExists;
        for (News n : c) {
            notExists = true;
            for (News ex : this) {
                if (n.id == ex.id) {
                    notExists = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (notExists)
                b.add(n);
        }
        return super.addAll(b);
    }
}
```

if I'm using those classes like this:

```
ArrayList<News> myNews = mDatabase.getNewsByOffset(5,10); // will return first 5 News from database
NewsArrayList<News> mDataset = new NewsArrayList<>();
mDataset.addAll(myNews);
myNews = mDatabase.getNewsByOffset(4,10); // will return first 4 News from database
mDataset.addAll(myNews);
```

Then will this code safe and optimized to not having dupplicate `News` items in `mDataset` ?

and just another quick question, this `break;`, breaking all `for-loop`s or the inner one only?

```
....
for (News n : c) {
    notExists = true;
    for (News ex : this) {
        if (n.id == ex.id) {
            notExists = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (notExists)
        b.add(n);
}
....
```

Comment: A `List` is the wrong collection type when you want avoid duplicates. Use an implementation of `Set` instead, eg. `TreeSet`, which preserves the order of elements, either their _natural order_ or the one determined by a `Comparator` plugged in on its instantiation.

Comment: is there any examples for my case? @TimothyTruckle

Comment: And for your last question, why don't you just put in sysout statements to check what happens if you reach break?

Comment: No exaples, just the contract for the Set interface at Java API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html and the TreeSet https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html And you should read the tutorial too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Comment: but `TreeSet` can not be for a dataset to using in adaptors @TimothyTruckle, Or my project structure will not permitt this.

Comment: The Set interface gives you the best approach for your business logic. You can always convert any collection into any other like this: `Set mySet = new TreeSet(); List myList = new ArrayList(mySet);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a collection with no duplicate consider using a `Set` instead, if you want to keep the order use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), you will simply need to override the methods `equals` and `hashCode` in your class `News`.

For example like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    final News news = (News) o;

    return this.id == news.id;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) (this.id ^ this.id >>> 32);
}
```

Your code would then be:

```
ArrayList<News> myNews = mDatabase.getNewsByOffset(5,10); // will return first 5 News from database
Set<News> mDataset = new LinkedHashSet<>(myNews);
myNews = mDatabase.getNewsByOffset(4,10); // will return first 4 News from database
mDataset.addAll(myNews);
```

---

However if you really need to use a `List` without duplicates, you can still proceed as next:

```
List<News> mDataset = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(myNews));
```

> and just another quick question, this break;, breaking all for-loops
>   or the inner one only?

It breaks the inner loop only to break all for loops use a label as next:

```
main: for (News n : c) {
    ...
    for (News ex : this) {
        if (n.id == ex.id) {
            ...
            // Break the loop with the label main
            break main;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry but what is this doing? `this.id ^ this.id >>> 32`

Comment: A `Set` can not be an itterator for an adapter in my project

Comment: It is what intellij generates, if you want to know what it does check the Bitwise Operators [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)

Comment: what do you mean by "A Set can not be an itterator for an adapter in my project " ?

Comment: I put an alternative, if you want to keep a `List`please check

Answer (score 0):

This approach can work, but isn't the most straightforward or efficient way to achieve this.

Generally, if you want to ensure that you only ever have one copy of a particular item in a collection, then you would use a **Set** rather than a List. A Set will automatically ensure that you don't have any duplicates.

In order for the Set to properly detect and avoid storing duplicates, you will need to implement **equals()** and **hashCode()** methods in your News class, so that it knows when to consider two News instances to be "the same". In your case, it looks like you will just refer to the "id" in order to uniquely identify each news item. Your IDE can probably generate equals()/hashCode() methods automatically - it is a common feature.

The most common Set implementation to use is **HashSet**. The main difference between using a HashSet and your approach is that the HashSet will not give you the items in the same order in which you added them. This may not be a problem. If it is, you can use **LinkedHashSet** instead